# Grim riddles'r'us

Tags: riddle

> Whenever you hear I'm here, you're filled with dread. When you see me, your heart breaks. Everyone fears me. What am I?

Everyone has experienced this at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is:

> a dead family member

Explanation:

> all people are 'filled with dread' when they hear they a loved one has passed.

> when you see a dead body you feel sad, or your 'heart breaks'.

> all people fear that someone close would pass away.

> Everyone has seen a family member die at least once.

***OLD ANSWER:***

I think it is:

> Death

Explanation:

> some people are 'filled with dread' when they hear they are going to die.

> when you see a dead body you feel sad, or your 'heart breaks'.

> most people fear death.

> Everyone dies once, which counts as 'at least once'.

Comment: "Has experienced" implies that everyone has *already* experienced it, which I don't think applies here. Also, the clue is "*Everyone* fears me", not "*some people* fear me"

Comment: fair enough I will think a bit more

Comment: It was death.yay.